# Replacing variables in Strings and properly allowing escaping

Tags: java, string-matching

I have a project where there are variables that need to be injected into Strings. Lets pretend I have the method written and its called `replaceVariables` and it replaces `{varaible}` with `foo`.

```
replaceVariables("This variable should be replaced {variable}")
    // "This variable should be replaced foo"

replaceVariables("This variable should NOT be replaced \\{variable\\}")
    // "This variable should NOT be replaced {variable}"

replaceVariables("This variable should be replaced \\\\{variable\\\\}")
    // "This variable should be replaced \foo\"
```

I could write a custom parser that detects backslashes and does all this but I really feel like i'm reinventing the wheel here.

Is there an implementation of this that does this in the Apache or Spring libraries? I know theres SPEL from spring but I feel that way over the top. Other possibility would be a regex but no matter how I try to build the regex it always seems like the negative look ahead would always need to look 1 before to check for an escaped `\`, aka you detect the backslash but maybe the backslash itself is escaped and so forth (although I kinda suck at regular expressions).

**Note:** I have to follow the `{variableName}` naming convention.

Comment: I think the third test doesn't make sense. If there's a literal \ within the curly braces the value within the curly braces is not *variable*

Comment: @bowmore Agreed. Case and point of why I dont want to write my own implemention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can safely be done with regular expressions :

```
public class VariableReplace {
    private class Substitution {
        private final String variable;
        private final String value;

        private Substitution(String variable, String value) {
            this.variable = variable;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getRegex() {
            return "((\\\\)*)\\{\\Q" + variable + "\\E\\}";
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return "$1" + value;
        }
    }

    private final List<Substitution> substitutions = new ArrayList<>();

    public void replace(String variable, String foo) {
        substitutions.add(new Substitution(variable, foo));
    }

    public String replaceVariables(String s) {
        String result = s;
        for (Substitution substitution : substitutions) {
            result = result.replaceAll(substitution.getRegex(), substitution.getValue());
        }
        result = result.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test class :

```
public class VariableReplaceTest {

    private VariableReplace variableReplace = new VariableReplace();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        variableReplace.replace("variable", "foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testNormal() {
        assertEquals("This variable should be replaced foo", variableReplace.replaceVariables("This variable should be replaced {variable}") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testEscaped() {
        assertEquals("This variable should NOT be replaced {variable}", variableReplace.replaceVariables("This variable should NOT be replaced \\{variable\\}") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleEscaped() {
        assertEquals("This variable should be replaced \\foo", variableReplace.replaceVariables("This variable should be replaced \\\\{variable}") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testVariableContainsRegexChars() {
        variableReplace.replace("var[iable", "foo");
        assertEquals("This variable should be replaced foo", variableReplace.replaceVariables("This variable should be replaced {var[iable}") );
    }

}
```

*caveat : further testing may be needed*

Answer (score 2):

You only need one line if you use `replaceAll()` with a regex that uses a negative look behind to assert the the curly brace is not escaped:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<![^\\\\]\\\\\\\\)\\{\\Q" + name + "\\E\\}", value));
```

### I deliberately discounted the trailing brace allowed to be preceded by an escaped backslash, since that is ridiculous.

Here's some test code:

```
String name = "foo", value = "bar";
String[] strs = {"abc {foo} def", "abc \\\\{foo} def", "abc \\\\\\\\{foo} def"};
for (String str : strs) 
    System.out.println(str + " --> " + str.replaceAll("(?<![^\\\\]\\\\\\\\)\\{\\Q" + name + "\\E\\}", value));
```

Output:

```
abc {foo} def --> abc bar def
abc \\{foo} def --> abc \\{foo} def
abc \\\\{foo} def --> abc \\\\bar def
```